# bower custom build of jqueryui

Tags: jquery-ui, bower

In [Bower](http://twitter.github.com/bower/), how do I get and continue to update a custom build of jQuery UI? Let's say I only need components for Core, Widget, Mouse, Position, Sortable, and Accordion in jQuery UI? I rather not download the entire jQuery UI library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could have your own fork, but then you would need to keep that up to date too. Just let it download the whole thing and only use the pieces you need, I don't see the problem with that.

Comment: Problem with downloading the whole thing (in my case at least) is a difference of 200+KB vs ~30KB.

Answer (score 15):

To give a practical example of a possible approach and to answer to Egg's comment here's a way to do it.

Just `bower install` the whole thing as suggested by Sindre and include only the scripts that you need in the html.

```
   <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/core.js"></script>
   <script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/widget.js"></script>
   <script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/mouse.js"></script>
   <script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/sortable.js"></script>
   <script>
     (function() {
       $( "#some-div" ).sortable();  // it works!
     })();
   </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

This will already work and reduce significantly the file size of the libraries downloaded by the user when using your app or website. Here is a post about this [straight from the horse's mouth](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/environments/bower/).

To further increase download speed you can then create your own bundle in your preferred way, maybe using [Grunt usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) or whatever else method you fancy to get to this kind of html:

```
   <script src="scripts/bundle.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     (function() {
       $( "#some-div" ).sortable(); // it works!
     })();
   </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this is the most practical approach to solving the problem and preventing conflicts with other libraries (e.g. tooltip from bootstrap)