# jQuery UI install via bower needed components only

Tags: jquery-ui, bower, bower-install

I know that i can install full jQuery UI pack via bower using `bower install jquery-ui --save`, or customize and download it from http://jqueryui.com/download/. But is there any way to install few components, for example **only effects core (effect.js) via bower**?

Comment: No, but Bower download everything (all themes and the components) so you can include the whole thing in your page, or only the components you  want to use

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056677/bower-custom-build-of-jqueryui)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Looks like i don't know how to use search system.